# Trouble logging out of a Facebook connect site and destroying sessions

Tags: php, session, facebook

I can't seem to get a facebook connect app that I am building to log the user out (sorry no url as it's still in dev). Each time the user clicks a link with the class "logout" the following JS runs which seems to work and even shows the FB modal stating the user has been logged out.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.logout').click(function(){
        //Kill facebook Session
        FB.Connect.logout(function() {
            window.location = $('.logout').attr("href");
        });
    });
});
```

Upon reaching the callback above, the JS sends the user to the logout page where PHP again forces the removal of a custom session and insures that the FB session was removed. Then the user is sent back to the page they were on when they clicked the "logout" link.

```
//Remove our site session
Auth::logout();



/* FAIL
//Send user to FB logout page and then back here
$logout_url = $this->fb->get_logout_url( site_url( $return_to ? base64_url_decode($return_to) : '' ) );

// Clear any stored state
$this->fb->clear_cookie_state();

exit(header("Location: ". $logout_url));
*/



//FAIL
//$this->fb->logout( site_url( $return_to ? base64_url_decode($return_to) : '' ) );


//FAIL
//Remove user (is this needed..?)
//$this->fb->set_user(NULL, NULL);


//Remove the FB session cookies (in case the JS didn't)
$this->fb->clear_cookie_state();


// Redirect to privious page
redirect( ( $return_to ? base64_url_decode($return_to) : '') );
```

However, this whole process results in the user being right back where they were and still logged in. A second click on the link seems to do the trick and remove the session though. I have monitored firebug (w/firecookie) and the PHP logout page reports deleting the FB session cookies - yet the next page loaded seems to still use them?!

If anyone knows how to completely <strike>DESTROY ALL FACEBOOKS</strike> ahem... sessions then please speak up.

:EDIT:
I have even tried to manually remove all cookies on the logout page and it still fails

```
if( $_COOKIE ) {

    foreach( $_COOKIE as $name => $value ) {

        //Get the current cookie config
        $params = session_get_cookie_params();

        // Delete the cookie from globals
        unset($_COOKIE[$name]);

        //Delete the cookie on the user_agent
        setcookie($name, '', time()-43200, $params['path'], '', $params['secure']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that because you are starting the Facebook api classes it reads the session and sets all the cookies again your Javascript call just cleared.

The php facebook lib and the FB js lib both use the same cookienames.
(so you can login through javascript and the php lib will be logged in as well).

There is a specific function for a log out and going to a URL by the way:

```
FB.Connect.LogoutAndRedirect(url);
```

Comment: How could PHP read the session (from the cookies) if the Javascript just cleared all the cookies?

Also, the LogoutAndRedirect has the same problem as using logout and then window.location (which is what I use).

Comment: javascript destroys the PHP_SESSION cookie ?  The data is stored somewhere, so that either means a cookie or post/get request parameter.

Comment: I know that canvas pages have GET params for each page - but not connect sites. And since window.location is used there is no POST data sent either. At any rate, you recommendation has me thinking now about some more things I can test so I'll accept your answer and then report back my findings.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `<fb:login-button>` tag and make sure you have `autologoutlink='true'`
Then, when the user is logged in, print out the `<fb:login-button>` tag and it will show up as a "Logout?" button

Hope that helps.

**EDIT:
The docos for login-button: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:login-button**

Comment: I'm afraid that the logout button is only useful for sites without a need for a callback. In other words, after the user clicks this button and logs out - they still have our site session and their is no way to refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (where the redirect page clears the server stuff)

```
            FB.logout(function(response) {
                window.location.href="/login/signout";
            });
```