# How to properly log out of facebook

Tags: facebook

This is a repeated question and I have followed both the suggestions provided in these StackOverflow links:

- [How to log-out users using FaceBook connect in php and zend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386557/how-to-log-out-users-using-facebook-connect-in-php-and-zend/1386749#1386749)
- [Trouble logging out of a FaceBook connect site and destroying sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546277/trouble-logging-out-of-a-facebook-connect-site-and-destroying-sessions)

The issue is - the code works 90% of the time. Thats the weird part. Out of the 100 times I've logged in and out - I've experienced this problem 5-6 times and 2 of my beta test users have reported the same issue.

So when it works- if u click the logout link - u get the facebook popup saying - you being logged out - when it does'nt work - absolutely nothing happens - the page does not refresh - it just sits on that page doing nothing.

This is the javascript code that gets called on clicking logout

```
function logout()
{
   FB.Connect.get_status().waitUntilReady(function(status) {
   switch(status) {
      case FB.ConnectState.connected:
        FB.Connect.logoutAndRedirect("http://www.example.com/login/logout");
        break;
      case FB.ConnectState.userNotLoggedIn:
        window.location = "http://www.example.com/login/logout";
        break;
}
});
return false;          
}
```

This is the php code:

```
$this->_auth->clearIdentity();
$face = Zend_Registry::get('facebook');
$fb = new Facebook($face['appapikey'], $face['appsecret']);
//$fb->clear_cookie_state();
$fb->expire_session();
```

Anyone experienced such sporadic issues.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks and sounds as though the `waitUntilReady` function never becomes "ready" and thereby prevents the rest of the code from executing. Perhaps try the following and let us know if it solves the problem:

```
function logout()
{
   var status = FB.Connect.get_status();
   switch(status) {
      case FB.ConnectState.connected:
        FB.Connect.logoutAndRedirect("http://www.example.com/login/logout");
        break;
      case FB.ConnectState.userNotLoggedIn:
        window.location = "http://www.example.com/login/logout";
        break;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dustin - I will use this code and will get back to you - I will probably need some time as this occurs very rarely........I will post my results soon - thanks for your time

Comment: Just wondering how it's working for you so far, and if you've seen the bug reoccur?